# redirect back not saving auth()->user

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I have a form to update user information including username. on the same page, there is a sidebar that has a profile button `href="{{route('profile',auth()->user())}}"`

once the form is saved I redirect to the same page, the route to update user info is

```
    Route::post('/profile/{user:name}/update' , 'ProfileController@update')->name('update-profile');
```

so it contains the name ( not the id).

the issue is when the page is redirected back to the same page the profile button is still containing the old user name, which leads to 404. Is there any solution to redirect back and updating the auth user in the sidebar with a new username?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange it should normally work. You can do

```php
 \Auth::setUser($newUser);
```

to set a new one.

Comment: thanks, man it works now. They should automatically change it